# Correct way of Putting a whole dynamic page into an If Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to generate different page results on a dynamic page depending on whether the page is either Niche 1 or Niche 2 for Insurance Providers (these are review pages and one is Travel (Niche 1) and the other is Pet (Niche 2).

I have created a simple statement and I can get the output to print either statement depending on whether that Insurer is Travel or Pet, so that bit works

```
<?php 
if ($broker_details->Niche_NicheID== '1'){
echo 'THIS IS NICHE 1';
} else {
    echo 'THIS IS NOT NICHE 1'
    ;}
    ?>
```

It will print correctly

THIS IS NICHE 1
or
THIS IS NOT NICHE 1

But when I try to put the whole page in, the layout is showing a coding error, I am simply cutting and pasting this entire block of code between the ' ' brackets instead of the 'THIS IS NICHE 1'.

The error is right at the start so I must be putting a bracket or apostrophe or something in the wrong place.

This is at the Start of the code I want t insert
[image: This is the start of the Code]

This is at the end of the code I want to insert.
[image: This is the end of the code]

I've tried putting the code in ' ' and this just turns all the divs to red, can anyone help, how should I enclose the page code correctly.

Thank you

Comment: You have an opening `<?php` tag but then later you throw in another one with `<php echo...` which is inside your earlier `echo`

Comment: You're not switching between PHP code and HTML code correctly. Please do not use images to show us code, use text.

Comment: I couldnt fit the code on it was too long and I didnt want to confuse the issue with incorrect code cut off at 30000 chars

Comment: I would recommend learning a PHP templating engine like `smarty` or `php plates`. This will allow you to create cleaner code and learn to separate HTML from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which part of your code is php and which part is html.

Try something like the following

```
<?php 
if ($broker_details->Niche_NicheID== '1'){ ?>

<div>I will be rendered as html</div>

<?php } else {
    echo 'THIS IS NOT NICHE 1';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

*From a general perspective:*

For determining the output of a large file **based on a single if statement** the easiest thing to do would be to **import different files** and then perform some standard actions to render the page.

**This could be a general implementation of this idea:**

```
<?php

//Import one of the php files based on a variable
require_once($niche_variable ? 'niche_class1.php' : 'niche_class2.php');

//Create a new object from the imported php file
$niche_class = new NicheClassObject();

//Perform some operations on the html, such as inserting values, or getting database information
$niche_class->performOperations();

//Render is the function that outputs HTML
echo $niche_class->render();

?>
```

**This is not the only way to do this. Of all the solutions, important factors are:**

1. Readability
2. Code/file organization
3. Compatibility with git and other versioning systems

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quotes and HTML code is throwing it off. Try putting all the code you want in the loop into a variable using `heredoc`. Like:

```
$loopcode = <<<EOT
<div class = "container">...</div> etc
EOT;
```

Then put the variable instead of code into your loop:

```
 <?php 
 if ($broker_details->Niche_NicheID== '1'){
 echo $loopcode;
 }
```

The longer way if you want to see the code in the loop:

```
if ($broker_details->Niche_NicheID== '1'){
print <<< END
<div class = "container">...</div> etc.
END;     
}
```